# An indentation error that shouldn't be there?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

I have been set a task to create a game that randomly generates 10 random numbers, shows them to the user in quick succession and after the user must go back to the start and remember if the next number was higher or lower.

I created a for loop to go through an array of numbers to quickly assign each of the ten variables with a random number, but in this for loop there is an indentation error. From previous experience with coding, I can't tell there is an indentation error. Please can someone help me and tell me what is going on?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SummerWorkTask2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int i, a, b;
            int [] n = new int[10];
            for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                n[i] = rnd.Next(1, 13);
            }
            a = rnd.Next(1,11);
            b= 0;
            while (b < a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This number is " + n[b]);
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                b++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line of code `n[i] = rnd.Next(1, 13);` is apparently not indented right, and even this site recognizes it, but I have tried everything, all number of spaces and apparently four spaces does not work.

The error i get is

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in SummerWorkTask2.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Visual studios then hihlights the line n[1] = rnd.Next91, 13);

If it is any use, I am coding in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: maybe you're worried about indentation because you're thinking how indentation works in Python? In C#, indentation will have no affect on the function of the code - when it compiles or when it runs. Indentation only matters for readability. *Whatever problem you're having (which you haven't explained) has nothing to do with indentation.*

Comment: @mmcrae The VS auto-indenter can be a canary in the syntactic coal mine.

Comment: If you hit "ctrl + k + d" in Visual Studio it should realign/re-indent your text.

Comment: you have an infinite-loop in your bottom `while` loop

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in SummerWorkTask2.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.      This is the Error i get.

Comment: mmcrae i would just like to say you are right i am new to C# and have previous expirence with Python, I have added more infomation and the error i get when I try to run the code, is this more useful?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this older post quite accidentially and I cannot believe why everyone was chatting about indentation in C# instead of reading the code and showing Scott the problem he had.

Okay, well here it is:

```
int [] n = new int[10];
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{ ... }
```

Creating an array with the size of `10`  like here ...

```
int [] n = new int[10];
```

... creates and array with `10` "slots" - from index `0` to `9`. I write each value as `?` into these slots since I don't want to confuse anyone with other numbers:

```
index         0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
array    n = [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?]
```

So you see there are `10` slots but since it is zero-based, there's no index `10`.

Now, in the next line, this loop is defined:

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) { ... }
```

It will run from `0` as long as `i` stays lower than `11`. Which actually is from `0` to `10`. That's one iteration more than the size of the array and that's why the last iteration (when `i==10`) will crash - it does not matter how often you delete and rewrite a code line or how deep it is indented.

```
loop i        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
array    n = [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?] [?]       <- BAM!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from *Visual Studio*. There is **no** indentation in C#.
And change `i<11` to `i<10` to prevent IndexOutOfRange Exception.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in SummerWorkTask2.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.